# Confusion on handling object types well

Tags: python, oop

It's probably obvious, but I'm pretty new to this.

If any good learning materials for this type of question come to mind I'd appreciate that as well.

Is there a way to handle child object instantiation based on the super type?

For example, if the object model is Person-Minor/Regular/Senior

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, full_name, age):
        self.species = "human"
        self.age = age
        self.first_name = full_name.split()[0]
        self.last_name = full_name.split()[1]
        self.age_classification = self.classify_age(self.age)

    def classify_age(self, input_age):
        if input_age < 18:
            return 'minor'
        elif input_age <= 64:
            return 'regular adult'
        elif input_age > 64:
            return 'senior'

class Minor(Person):
    def __init__(self):
        self.number_older_siblings = 0
        self.number_younger_siblings = 0

    def is_unloved(self):
        if self.number_older_siblings > 0 and self.number_younger_siblings > 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Is there any clean way to declare a person, such that if they are under 18 it will "automatically" be a child type object?

Ex not have to do

```
my_person = Person('John Smith', 15)

if my_person.age_classification == 'minor':
    my_person = Minor()
    my_person.number_older_siblings = 1
    my_person.number_younger_siblings = 1
    print(my_person.is_unloved())
```

But just be able to have that inferred if the declaration satisfies a condition

```
my_person = Person('John Smith', 15)

my_person.number_older_siblings = 1
my_person.number_younger_siblings = 1
print(my_person.is_unloved())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Moira Jones' solution is good, but here's one step further you can take it:

```
class Person:

    @staticmethod
    def create(full_name, age):
        if age <= 18:
            return Minor()
        else:
            return Person(full_name, age)

    def __init__(self, full_name, age):
        self.species = "human"
        self.age = age
        self.first_name = full_name.split()[0]
        self.last_name = full_name.split()[1]
        self.age_classification = self.classify_age(self.age)

    def classify_age(self, input_age):
        if input_age < 18:
            return 'minor'
        elif input_age <= 64:
            return 'regular adult'
        elif input_age > 64:
            return 'senior'

class Minor(Person):
    def __init__(self):
        self.number_older_siblings = 0
        self.number_younger_siblings = 0

    def is_unloved(self):
        if self.number_older_siblings > 0 and self.number_younger_siblings > 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

print(type(Person.create("John Smith", 19)))
print(type(Person.create("Bob Smith", 12)))
```

Output:

> < class '__main__.Person'>
>   < class '__main__.Minor'>

If we make `create()` a static method of the parent class, we can use it in the same way as the function Moira suggested, but it can live with the class definition instead of being a function floating off on its own. I think this makes the relationship between the function and the objects it operates on more clear. Note that static methods do not receive a `self` parameter like other object methods do.

Comment: Woah. That is 100% coincidence that the example in the static method tutorial is almost exactly the one I used https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/class-method-vs-static-method-python/

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you write a function to instantiate `Person`s?

```
def create_person(full_name, age):
    if age <= 18:
        return Minor()
    else:
        return Person(full_name, age)
```

Then:

```
>>> type(create_person("John Smith", 19))
__main__.Person

>>> type(create_person("Bob Smith", 12))
__main__.Minor
```

Also, you might want to make the constructor for `Minor` also take `full_name` and `age`.

Comment: This is good. I'll keep the question open for a bit because I'm interested to learn alternate approaches but probably end up accepting this answer.